# How could I downgrade CnosDB?

Tags: database, cnosdb

I am setting up a CnosDB cluster with the [latest version 2.2](https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/releases/tag/v2.2.0) and loading piles of CSV files. There might be some breaking fix I suspect. How could I downgrade to previous version with some simple command?

```
cnosdbd downgrade 2.1.0
```